# Using node readdir and getting an undefined error not sure why learnyounode

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

When I run the below list[i] on line 14 returns as undefined and I am not sure why. Especially since my log on line 10 returns as expected. below is the code,

```
  1 var fs = require('fs');                                                          
  2 var thatDir = process.argv[2];                                                   
  3 var ext = process.argv[3];                                                       
  4 var newfile;                                                                     
  5 fs.readdir(thatDir, function(err, list){                                        
  6     console.log(list);                                                          
  7     console.log(ext);                                                           
  8     console.log('banana' + list[0]);                                            
  9     var wtf = list[0].toString();                                               
 10     var anotherwtf = wtf.search('.' + ext);                                     
 11     console.log(anotherwtf);                                                    
 12     console.log('wtf is ' + wtf);                                               
 13     for(var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++){                                      
 14         if ( list[i].search('.' + ext) != -1 ){                                 
 15         console.log(list[i]);                                                   
 16         }                                                                       
 17     }                                                                           
 18 });
```

Comment: So what is the output you are getting, and what parts of it are unexpected (and what would you have expected)? What arguments do you pass to your script, and what files does the directory contain?

Comment: `search` does take a regular expression, not a string! Use `indexOf` instead.

Comment: sorry for not clarifying, the input coming in from process.argv[2] is an array. so var thatDir is an array. list.length does have a length. The error coming up as undefined is the .search on the list[i], however when I called out a specific one, like on line 10 for some reason  it works fine. Even if I remove the 'tostring()' so I dont understand why it makes a difference in the for loop. When I remove the if statement it consoles each file in the array just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do `i < list.length` using less than `<` instead of less than or equal to `<=`.

The array is 0 indexed, you start getting items from `list[0]`, and there are items for all the `i` from 0 to `list.length - 1`, but `list[list.length]` does not exist.

Comment: edited. I see what you are saying now. Interesting the console threw the error it did. Really confused me. Thanks man! Happy to see I was pretty much there.

Comment: Cool! Glad you sorted it!